# How to integrate the POST api with this payload?

Tags: reactjs

{
"title":"Sec Engg",
"tasks":[{
"title":"Task A",
"effortEstimated":1.3
}]
}

Comment: I need to set the name & value  for the input field ,will u plzz show how to do that .?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch API provided by Javascript.

```
const data = { "title":"Sec Engg", "tasks":[{ "title":"Task A", "effortEstimated":1.3 }] };

fetch('http://example.com/movies.json', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
       'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
     body: JSON.stringfy(data),
    .then(response => response.json());
    .then(data => { console.log('Success', data)
    })
     .catch((error) => { console.log('Error', error)}
 });
```

Comment: let submitProduct = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let dataURL = `url`;
        Axios.post(dataURL ,job).then((response) => {
            setSubmitted(true);
        }).catch((err) => {
            setErrorMessage(err);
        });
    };

Answer (score 0):

You can use (Built in) [Fetch Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [axios library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api) to integrate POST Api with it's payload.

Using Fetch :

```
 async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'        
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  });
  return response.json(); 
}
```

Using axios:

```
async function getPostData(params={}){

  const response =  await axios.post('http://something.com/', params);
  return response;

}
```

Comment: I need to set the name & value  for the input field ,will u plzz tell how to do that .?

Comment: I tried like this -->  <input type="number" placeholder=" Effort Estimated  "
        name="tasks"
        value={job.tasks.effortEstimated}
        onChange={changeInput}
                           />